# How to make an insert, if not null result of a select in a single query?

Tags: mysql

This is what I tried to do:

```
INSERT INTO `table2` SET `coditem`=(SELECT `tb1`.`cod`
                               FROM `table1` as `tb1`
                               WHERE `tb1`.`cod` = '4F576DC' 
                               AND `tb1`.`user` = 'CB78005'),
             `coduser`='CB78005', `date`= NOW(),`textsdata`='2',`active`='1';
```

I have two tables.

One with the client's registry (**table1**) and another with the request for changes requested by the client (**table2**).

When the user makes a request, I will have the code of the item (**coditem**), and the code of the user (**coduser**) who made the request.

For security, in select (**SELECT `tb1`.`cod` FROM `table1` as `tb1` WHERE `tb1`.`cod` = '4F576DC' AND `tb1`.`user` = 'CB78005'**) I check if the item is same as the user who is requesting for the request. For it would be easy to change this code on the form. I must prevent the client from trying to modify the item from other users.

When all is well, it works perfectly. But when the code of the item is not of the client, the select returns null and gives an error.

[image]

How can I solve this problem when  return null?

When the select returns null the insert should not be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rewriting your insert as a pure `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (coditem, coduser, date, textsdata, active)
SELECT t1.cod, 'CB78005', NOW(), '2', '1'
FROM table1 t1
WHERE
    t1.cod = '4F576DC' AND
    t1.user = 'CB78005';
```

As written above, if the `cod` value were `NULL`, no insert at all would happen.  There is probably a better way to express your logic, but this might fix your immediate problem.